# Calculating Fourier Coefficients By Excel

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-series

I'm trying to use Excel to calculate Fourier coefficients.
But I'm confused on which method should be used to used to approximate $$\int f(x)\cos(x)dx$$ and $$\int f(x)\sin(x)dx $$.

$1.\quad$ trapezoid $\cos(x)$     &        trapezoid $\sin(x)$

$2.\quad$ trapezoid  definite integral $\cos(x)dx$  & trapezoid definite integral $\sin(x)dx$

I found an example excel sheet (https://quickfield.com/harmonics_analysis_excel.htm) that seems to takes the definite integral of the cosine & sine term.

Is this a more accurate method than averaging $f(x)\cos(x)$ and $f(x)\sin(x)$ normally?

Comment: This sounds brutal.

Comment: Numerical integration in excel is probably more accurate than averaging the functions yes, because to calculate an accurate average requires integration anyway. You could use something like trapezium rule or even just rectangles

Comment: But what about combination of numerical integration for F(X) and definite integral of the Cosine & Sine component?